# Метод cloneDeep в библиотеке lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Как добиться той же функциональности cloneDeep чистым JS ?

Comment: Написать рекурсивную функцию создания объекта на основе исходного (берём ключ, если его значение примитив, то создаём такой же в новом объекте, если же ключ ссылается на некий объект то рекурсивно вызываем функцию и т.д.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `spread syntax` и `Object.assign()`, однако глубокого копирования всё равно не добиться. Думаю, можно пойти еще более хитрым способом - конвертировать в JSON а потом обратно в объект.